# Best way to return price with decimals from Model

Tags: laravel, model, decimal, laravel-9

In my model I have total price calculation based on hasMany relationship. It looks like this:

```
public function totalPrice(): string
{
    return num_format($this->hasMany(Direction::class)->sum('price'));
}
```

I use num_format function which is described in helper.php file. In case I need to change number formatting I can always edit helper function. But I wonder if there be a better/nicer way to do this? As far as I understand I can't use $casts for function in this situation? What are your thoughts? Do you think apporach I'm using is correct?
Thank you for your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is fine, I personally would decouple the relation, then have totalPrice be `num_format($this->directions()->sum('price'))`

If you wanted a global way of defining this, you can define a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#writing-global-scopes) which would be called something like `sumWithDp` and then in any model with a defined relation you can call:

`$this->relation()->sumWithDp('price', $decimalPlaces)`

(or just always have it be 2 DP if you wanted)